# Triple chain rule problem

Tags: calculus

$$ f(x) = \log _4 \log _2 \tan x $$
$$ f'(x) = \frac{1}{log _2 (\tan x) \ln (4)} \cdot \frac{1}{\cos ^2x \tan x \ln (2)}=  $$
Is there anything else I can do with this besides changing $\tan x$ to $\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$ and getting rid of cos's square?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As $\displaystyle\frac{d(\ln y)}{dy}=\frac1y$ and $\displaystyle\log_ab=\frac{\log_cb}{\log_ca}$

$$\log_4(\log_2\tan x)=\frac{\ln (\log_2\tan x)}{\ln 4}$$

Now, $$\frac{d\{\ln (\log_2\tan x)\}}{dx}=\frac{d\{\ln (\log_2\tan x)\}}{d(\log_2\tan x)}\frac{d(\log_2\tan x)}{dx}=\frac1{\log_2\tan x}\frac{d(\log_2\tan x)}{dx}$$

Again, $\displaystyle\log_2\tan x=\frac{\ln\tan x}{\ln2}$

Now, $$\frac{d(\ln\tan x)}{dx}=\frac{d(\ln\tan x)}{d(\tan x)}\frac{d(\tan x)}{dx}=\frac1{\tan x}\sec^2x$$

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary to use logarithmic differentiation here?

Comment: @user98079, not sure if logarithm is complex to you or not? Else you can express $x$ in terms of $f(x)$

Comment: @DepeHb, $$\frac{\sec^2x}{\tan x}=\frac{\cos x}{\sin x\cos^2x}=\frac1{\sin x\cos x}=\frac2{\sin2x}=2\csc2x$$

Comment: I can use logatithmic differentiation but I thought I could simply apply chain rule here.

Comment: @user98079, we need to & we have applied chain rule, but need to take some care as here the base of logarithm is not $e$

Comment: Could you explain the third line little bit (after "Now,"). I'm trying to figure out what you did there but it is difficult to follow.

Comment: @user98079, there starts the usage of Chain Rule as after the second now